# Error: 'Connection closed...' when cloning a project form bitbucket

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I am having a problem connecting to bitbucket recently. There is no problem when I want to connect to GitHub, for example. However, when I want to clone the project I get this error:

```
Connection closed by 18.205.93.1 port 22
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I am 100% sure I have access right and the repository exists. I have created many different keys and put it in my bitbucket as well, but it hasn't changed anything. I run this `ssh -v git@bitbucket.org` to get some more information. This is what I see:

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [18.205.93.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\nipek/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
...
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
...
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:zzXQOX...
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\nipek/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:M7dEqyz... C:\\Users\\nipek/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to bitbucket.org ([18.205.93.2]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: console supports the ansi parsing
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
logged in as LukNie.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to bitbucket.org closed.
Transferred: sent 2732, received 1852 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 9222.4, received 6251.8
debug1: Exit status 0
```

I had problems with my system recently and I lost some files because part of my system 'returned to initial settings'. I wonder if there is some misconfiguration between files and that is the reason, however I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround. It is not a perfect solution but at least it works. Here is an explanation https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/troubleshoot-ssh-issues-271943403.html under "If port 22 is blocked". In general, if there is some problem with port 22, one can use port 443 like this:

```
git clone ssh://git@altssh.bitbucket.org:443/<account_name>/<repo_name>/
```

Comment: If port 22 was blocked then you would get errors from `ssh -v git@bitbucket.org`.

Comment: I do not think that my problem was with port 22 but that solution with port 443 worked for me

Comment: Have no problems with port 22 but this workaround helped