# ssh git clone error "Connection to bitbucket.org closed by remote host" on ubuntu 22

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh

I'm on ubuntu desktop 22 and I have installed  git version 2.37.1, I'm trying to clone a repository using ssh after some minutes apper this error:

"Connection to bitbucket.org closed by remote host"

Any idea?

Comment: I was doing tests with other repositories under the same environment, and I realized that the only repository that gives me this problem is around 520 Mb.

Answer (score 1):

I found 2 problems.

1. The repository were too big more that 600 Mb.
2. My internet had problems with bandwidth.

So, I found a git command for clone just a part of history commits.
This helped to clone my proyect althogh my internet bad bandwidth.

```
git clone --depth=1 -b your_branch_name git@bitbucket.org:benjamin_castillo/my_own_proyect.git
```

Answer (score 0):

You should trace network connection by this command:

> `GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git push --progress -v origin`

You can view this helpful links:

**[Connection to bitbucket.org closed by remote host](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Connection-to-bitbucket-org-closed-by-remote-host/qaq-p/721558)**

*[Connection closed... when cloning a project form bitbucket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56198773/5661396)*

Comment: This help me to understand the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Benjamin, You can mark  and upvote answer as a correct answer to help others.